# MVC3 - Process something every X amount of time

Tags: wcf, web-services, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm very new to web programming with MVC so i dont know how to call a method, for example,  every hour and also on command. (Method is supposed to fetch files from an FTP server, skip the already parsed files, and parse the ones that havent been into objects and insert them in a database)

I know if i were using WindowsForms i'd probably be using Timer.Tick Events, WPF would use the DispatcherTimer class, but a web server is a whole different ball game so could somebody please point me in the right direction?

Ive been reading about Web services, WCF? Some event driven thing?

All i have right now is an MVC3 project, a database, repositories using EF, the whole works..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to [use the Task Scheduler to access a particular URL](http://www.ehow.com/how_5765885_open-automatically.html) in your site on a given interval.

I.E. Make use of something that already works very well as a general purpose mechanism on your platform... rather than unnecessarily reinventing for a specific use.

Comment: Nice and easy.. I dont think I have access though to the Task Scheduler in the server where im going to deploy the webpage though.. are there any other solutions?

Comment: @seed_87: This type of scheduling is bread and butter for managing web sites and web services. It might not be Windows Task Scheduler but any hosting company worth its salt should provide some sort of task scheduling mechanism. Who are you hosting with? http://discountasp.net/ for example lists a task scheduler as one of its hosting tools on its home page.

Comment: Its a local webpage hosted on a local web server which i dont manage.., im sorry i cant give you more information asi I myself dont know much.. I'll ask and see if it can be done that way.

Cant i just spawn a backgroundworker from Global.asax Application_Startup ?